# "X is distributed as ..." notation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

A question about notation:

We sometimes use $\sim$ to denote "distributed as" e.g. if $X$ is Gaussian we write $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Is it acceptable to use the "~" notation for an arbitrary distribution? e.g. can we write

$$X \sim \begin{cases} \frac{3}{2}x^2, & x \in [-1,1] \\0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

If not, is there another way to write "$X$ is distributed as ..."? i.e. without the more verbose "Let $p_X(x)$ be the pdf of $X$. Then $p_X(x)=$ ...

Comment: Formally you take one probability space where $P$ is the probability measure defined on this space and you take a measurable space say $(E,\mathcal{E})$, then there is an induced probability measure $P_X$ on $E$. This is the probability distribution which you are after. For the $\sim$ sign, as long as I know it is used for distribution functions. If one uses it for the density function, it is also understandable, whether it is common, I cannot say that.

Comment: Related question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531826/reference-who-introduced-the-tilde-notation-to-mean-has-probability-distri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no huge problem with the notation though you don't see it a lot. It's reasonably clear what you mean, and that's pretty much the goal with notation.

However I don't think "Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF $p_X(x) = \ldots$" is overly verbose. You could even say "Let $p_X(x) = \ldots$" since $p_X$ and $f_X$ are pretty standard notations for the PDF, but I think the first option has the right balance of clarity and efficiency for my taste.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not that rare to see $X\sim f_X(x)$ as a shorthand for $X$ is distributed according to $f_X(x)$. However, I've never encountered in any formal settings your version ($\sim$ followed by brackets etc.).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, I think it's more common to write 
$$X\sim \frac32x^2I(-1\le x\le 1)\color{red}{dx}$$
in your case.

Comment: The indicator function makes sense. But why is there a $dx$?

Comment: @dkv this unambiguously says it is a PDF and nothing else.

Comment: I see. I've never encountered this notation before. Would you know any textbooks that introduce it?

Comment: @dkv can't recall particular textbooks that contain it. But I'm sure I've seen it once or twice at least.

Comment: Never saw $X\sim f_X(x)dx$.

Comment: @Did I think it's a good notation anyway.

Comment: @Did standard notation, see eg. any Book by Schilling